# AWS Glue- Data Lineage and Job Tracking

Tags: aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog, data-lineage, aws-glue-spark, aws-glue-workflow

Is there a way to track what each job we create in AWS Glue is doing? For e.g., if jobs doing the same action are created twice, the data lineage of data while going through each transformation?